# How to use field "ID" as index in pandas dataframe and skip one row when reading xls file?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset of default credit card payments. I need to skip 1 row above and make ID the actual index in pandas dataframe.

```
dataset = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/erjan222/default of credit card clients.xls',header =0)
dataset.head()
```

[image: kk]

How can i do this?
using the first column "ID" as index column does not help.

```
dataset = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/erjan222/default of credit card clients.xls',index_col=1)
```

[image: ii]

Comment: `index_col=['ID']`? Although it looks like your header is not correct still.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
dataset = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/erjan222/default of credit card clients.xls', index_col=0, skiprows=1)
```

Result:

```
    LIMIT_BAL  SEX
ID                
1        2000    2
2      120000    2
3       90000    2
```